# Going back with react-router if previous visit is from another web site

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I believe this is a very well know and solved issue on router but perhaps I was not able to search properly in order to find the already answered question. Sorry in advance.

I am developing a react application with react router enabled. When I am browsing in the app itself all is fine. Using the history.goBack() works properly. But when it comes to a visit from another web page. The history.goBack brings me to the previous page, instead I would like to go to another page in my app. I think there are some solutions available. But still not sure;

1. Do not draw the go back button if router history is empty.
2. Modify the router history manually. So that the going back will keep me in my own app.

Comment: use canGoBack and for replace use history.replace()

Comment: is canGoBack available in v4 ?

Comment: const canGoBack = window.history.length > 1

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to react-router if you are visiting from another web URL. In that case, vanilla javascript can help you out.

```
document.referrer
```

This one refers to the previous url you have visited. So simple you can use `window` object to go back.

```
window.location.href = document.referrer
```

Comment: OP asking for the react-router solution so its good to tell him the react solution